# How do I share my jQuery plugin with the world?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I made a plugin for jQuery, which I think is quite useful. It combines an animated colours plugin with an easings plugin, and adds a completely new feature of being able to refer to colours numerically (more useful in hex notation, so 0xff00cc for example) and therefore manipulate them mathematically more easily.

I created a repository on github, and it sits there, nobody looks at it.

Mostly, I would like people to look at it, use it, and improve it, so I can use the improvements and so on. I think this idea of numerically manipulating colors could be interesting. It makes it easy to change the hue without changing the saturation for example. Combined with animated colors, I think something interesting could be done, but I don't know what exactly. How do I let people know it (or any other project) is there..?

I was going to post it on http://plugins.jquery.com which is currently down. Are there any other outlets for this kind of code?

Comment: github, blogblog, facebook (groups), twitter, google plus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the blog post that explains [what happened to the plugin repository](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/12/08/what-is-happening-to-the-jquery-plugins-site/):

> We recognize that the old site was still serving as an regular resource for a lot of people, especially newer jQuery users, who simply valued the existence of a central browsing location, despite its flaws. Though many experienced users had moved on to other sites, or relied on relationships with trusted authors and word of mouth, these can take time to develop. Until we’re able to launch the new system, we’re happy to direct you to several other directories and people who can help pick up the slack:
>
> - [jQuery List](http://jquerylist.com/)
> - [jQuery Style](http://jquerystyle.com/)
> - [Mike Alsup](http://jquery.malsup.com/)
> - [Ben Alman](https://github.com/cowboy)
> - [Matteo Bicocchi](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/components.html)
> - [Jörn Zaefferer](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/)
>
> If, in the process of searching these or any other directories, you are directed back to the current site at plugins.jquery.com, typically a quick search for the author’s name and the plugin name will yield an alternative site where it was hosted. In addition, [DailyJS just did a useful roundup of alternatives](http://dailyjs.com/2011/12/06/jquery-roundup/) that goes into more detail.

The DailyJS article suggests one more alternative for promoting your plugin, [The Handpicked jQuery Plugins Repository](http://iwantaneff.in/repo/). Now, all that wasn't very hard to find, was it?

Additionally, you should consider [ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/):

> Ohloh is a new kind of software directory, combining community-driven content with a unique source code crawler that monitors up-to-date development activity.

Ohloh generates a set of incredible reports for your project, to get a quick idea check out this [Firefox vs Chrome](http://www.ohloh.net/p/compare?project_0=Mozilla+Firefox&project_1=Chromium+%28Google+Chrome%29) comparison.

Lastly, a very good place for `people to look at it, use it, and improve it` is [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Share it.

If you have a blog, blog about it. If you don't have a blog, get one and start blogging about it. There are few things more reassuring to someone who's researching a component than finding a project owner who actively discusses their project. It's one of the criteria I use when choosing components. If the developer is actively talking about it then that means there's a fair chance I'll be able to get support for it.

Recommend it.

If you're not already active on stackoverflow, that's a good place to start. Become a participant in questions for relevant tags and then consider recommending your component as a solution, where appropriate. **Note:** The 'where appropriate' bit is very important. Don't take a scattershot approach of "spamming" questions as the community will not be appreciated and is a very easy way to lose credibility. Always ensure that you adopt a full disclosure approach and explain that you're recommending a component you wrote and WHY it's a good fir for the original question.

Use It.

Look for projects that you can participate in where it might be a good fit and consider recommending it. You'll also gain valuable feedback on your feature-set this way which can be used to improve your component.